# Open Documents in Recent Items sub-Menu

Tags: applescript

I wrote this AppleScript to open selected items from the 'Recent Items' sub-menu via a choose from list dialog. It works for the first item, and then exits gracefully, with out going on to open the other items.

You'll see below, that I added some 'display dialogs' to give me an idea if it should work, and everything indicates that it should. Still, it doesn't...

```
tell application "Finder"
    activate
    try
        tell application "System Events"
            tell process "Finder"
                tell menu "Recent Items" of menu item "Recent Items" of menu 1 of menu bar 1
                    set menuItemNames to (get name of (every menu item whose position ≠ missing value and name ≠ "Applications" and name ≠ "Documents" and name ≠ "Servers" and name ≠ missing value))
                    set text item delimiters of AppleScript to ","
                    set targetMenuItems to (choose from list menuItemNames with prompt "Choose a recent document to view:" with title "Recent Documents" OK button name "Open" with multiple selections allowed) as list
                    set targetMenuItems to (text items of targetMenuItems as text)
                    if targetMenuItems ≠ "false" then
                        set menuitemCount to (count text items in targetMenuItems)
                        display dialog menuitemCount
                        display dialog (text item 1 of targetMenuItems)
                        set x to 1
                        repeat menuitemCount times
                            set targetItem to (text item x of targetMenuItems)
                            display dialog targetItem
                            click menu item targetItem
                            set x to x + 1
                        end repeat
                    end if
                end tell
            end tell
        end tell
    on error errorMsg
        display dialog errorMsg
    end try
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

I might be missing some reason why the list was converted to text, but this seems to work with multiple items:

```
delay 0.3
tell application "System Events" to tell (process 1 where it is frontmost)
    tell menu 1 of menu item "Recent Items" of menu 1 of menu bar 1
        set menuitems to name of (menu items where position is not missing value and name is not "Applications" and name is not "Documents" and name is not "Servers" and name is not "Clear Menu" and name is not missing value)
        tell application (path to frontmost application as text)
            activate
            choose from list menuitems with multiple selections allowed
        end tell
        repeat with m in result
            click menu item m
        end repeat
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: This seems to work perfectly, so long as you add  'tell application "Finder' to activate' at the beginning. Thanks for the help!